# Remove suffix if string matches regular expression in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In one of my columns, I would like to remove a suffix from certain strings where it matches a pattern. This is a snippet of my column data:

```
col1
DS-71007-002-1
DN-80013-002-6
2"-VH-11008-MW01-03
```

This is what I would like:

```
col1
DS-71007-002
DN-80013-002
2"-VH-11008-MW01-03
```

I'm basically just remove the `-1` and `-6` from the first two lines.

I'm not very good with regular expressions. I just came up with this:

`[A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]`

But unsure how to go about then removing the suffixes from strings that match this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex with a lookbehind:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'(?<=^\w{2}-\d{5}-\d{3})(-\d+)', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
                  col1                 col2
0       DS-71007-002-1         DS-71007-002
1       DN-80013-002-6         DN-80013-002
2  2"-VH-11008-MW01-03  2"-VH-11008-MW01-03
```

You can [test the regex here](https://regex101.com/r/OtieRj/1), in summary this is

```
(?<=   # lookbehind
^      # match beginning of string
\w{2}  # 2 word characters
-      # a dash
\d{5}  # 5 digits
-      # a dash
\d{3}  # 3 digits
)      # end of lookbehind
(      # capturing group (what will be replaced by the empty string)
-\d+   # 1 dash and one or more digits
)      # end of capturing group
```

Comment: Great thank you. I've been trying to apply this kind of code - `r'(?<=^\w{2}-\d{5}-\d{3})(-\d+)'` to another string `6-OX-1011022-DWJ06-PG-04` however couldn't seem to get it working. What does the `(-\d+)` represent?

Comment: @AaronWright I provided details

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html). No need of `regex`:

```
In [915]: import numpy as np

In [916]: df['col1'] = np.where(df.col1.str.split('-').str[-2].str.isnumeric(), df.col1.str.split('-').str[:-1].str.join('-'), df.col1)

In [917]: df
Out[917]: 
                  col1
0         DS-71007-002
1         DN-80013-002
2  2"-VH-11008-MW01-03
```